# equal() function in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, equals

I need if two objects are `equal()` need to `print("Equal")`  if objects are not equal -> "Not equal".I can not find mistake of this code[This is my code in IntelliJ IDEA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kr6J2.png)
As a side note, when we override equals(), it is recommended to also override the hashCode() method. If we don’t do so, equal objects may get different hash-values; and hash based collections, including HashMap, HashSet, and Hashtable do not work properly (see this for more details). We will be covering more about hashCode() in a separate post.
References:

```
internal class Complex(private val re: Double, private val im: Double) {
    // Overriding equals() to compare two Complex objects
    fun equals(o: Object): Boolean {

        // If the object is compared with itself then return true
        if (o === this) {
            return true
        }

        /* Check if o is an instance of Complex or not
          "null instanceof [type]" also returns false */if (o !is Complex) {
            return false
        }

        // typecast o to Complex so that we can compare data members
        val c = o as Complex

        // Compare the data members and return accordingly
        return (java.lang.Double.compare(re, c.re) == 0
                && java.lang.Double.compare(im, c.im) == 0)
    }
} // Driver class to test the Complex class

    fun main(args: Array<String>) {
        val c1 = Complex(12.0, 15.0)
        val c2 = Complex(10.0, 15.0)
        if (c1 == c2) {
            println("Equal ")
        } else {
            println("Not Equal ")
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the error show when you hover your mouse over the squiggles?

Comment: Object is not a Kotlin data type. === is not a Kotlin operator.

Comment: @lukas.j That's the Kotlin reference equality operator, which is sensible to use in an `equals()` implementation, although of course in this case this class can just be a data class.

Comment: In Kotlin, you must _always_ specify `override` when overriding (or implementing) a superclass/interface method/property — so you should get into the habit of using it. In this case, it would have given `error: 'equals' overrides nothing`, showing where the problem lies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [data class](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/data-classes.html) would make more sense:

```
data class Complex(
  private val re: Double,
  private val im: Double
)

val c1 = Complex(12.0, 15.0)
val c2 = Complex(10.0, 15.0)

if (c1 == c2) {
  println("Equal")
} else {
  println("Not Equal")
}
```

Output: Not Equal

Answer (score 2):

In Kotlin, you use Any instead of Object. It will not allow you to test if your class instance is an Object, only Any.

Also, you are failing to override `equals` since you didn't use the `override` keyword. The argument needs to be `Any?`, not `Object`.

Change

```
fun equals(o: Object): Boolean {
```

to

```
override fun equals(o: Any?): Boolean {
```

Also, in this case, you should use a data class so you won't have to write your own `equals()` implementation in the first place.

And in the future, when you aren't using a data class, you can use the IDE option to generate `equals` and `hashcode` for you automatically.